# Branch.initSession not returning data in Ionic v1 on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, branch.io

I have installed and configured branch as documented. Everything works fine on Android, but I am not able to make it work on iOS.

Here is what I followed.

Ionic v1 project

1. Created Branch account and configured everything.
2. Configured keys, domains etc in config.xml file.
3. Calling branchInit() on deviceready and resume event.

```js
function branchInit() {
  // Branch initialization
  if (Branch) {
    Branch.initSession(function(data) {
      alert("Branch Data", JSON.stringify(data));
      if (data['+clicked_branch_link']) {
        alert("Yes");
      } else {
        alert("No");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have created a link on branch similar to this.

`https://abc.app.link/myurl`

Click on the link from notes app.

On Android this seems to work fine. Data is returned and I am getting the Yes alert and I can log the data.

On iOS the data is not being returned. **The control is not even entering the Branch.initSession method**, and I don't see any alerts.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: I tried removing all Cordova plugins and added one by one and tested each build. there was a clash with `Branch` and `CodePush` plugins